# Draw line at center of circle with angle in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, geometry, core-graphics

I want to draw line at the center of circle with fixed size. Please check the image, it will explain everything. I have P1 center of the circle and P2 somewhere at the border of the circle. P1 will always remain fixed and P2 will keep changing with mouse move and it will be any point at circle's border. Now, I want to draw line with fixed length shown in green color. I want to find the (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) with fixed distance, every time P2 get changed, i want to draw green line facing towards P2.

[image]

Hope, image explains everything, in short i need following.

1. angle between P1 and P2.
2. Draw green line with fixed distance with angle at the center of the circle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you (apparently) want the green line to be perpendicular to the red line, you don't need to compute the angle between p1 and p2.  Rotating a vector by 90˚ is quite trivial.

I assume you have p1 and p2 as `CGPoint` (or `NSPoint`) variables.

First let's compute the vector from p1 to p2:

```
CGPoint p1p2 = CGPointMake(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y);
```

Next we'll compute a vector that is perpendicular to the p1->p2 vector:

```
CGPoint p1p2Perp = CGPointMake(p1p2.y, -p1p2.x);
```

Now let's find the length of the perpendicular vector:

```
CGFloat radius = hypot(p1p2Perp.x, p1p2Perp.y);
```

Note that if the radius of the circle is constant, you can just use that instead of computing it.  If you're on iOS, use `hypotf` instead of `hypot`.

So now we can “normalize” the perpendicular vector, making it have length 1, by dividing its coordinates by its length:

```
p1p2Perp.x /= radius;
p1p2Perp.y /= radius;
```

Next we can multiply it by *half* of the desired length of the green line.  I assume you have the desired length of the green line in a constant or variable named `greenLineLength`.

```
p1p2Perp.x *= greenLineLength / 2;
p1p2Perp.y *= greenLineLength / 2;
```

Now we can create a path for the green line.  I assume your `CGContextRef` is in a variable named `gc`:

```
CGContextBeginPath(gc);
CGContextMoveToPoint(gc, p1.x - p1p2Perp.x, p1.y - p1p2Perp.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(gc, p1.x + p1p2Perp.x, p1.y + p1p2Perp.y);
```

You can stroke the path however you like.  For example:

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(gc, 0, 1, 0, 1);
CGContextSetLineWidth(gc, 2);
CGContextSetLineCap(gc, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextStrokePath(gc);
```

Answer (score 0):

The angle between the two, according to your question, is always perpendicular -- 90˚ or π/2 radians. You can get the angle of the red segment using [`atan2()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/atan2.3.html); then subtract `M_PI_2` for the angle of the green one.

From there, you are trying to find two points on the circumference of a circle whose diameter is the length of the segment. You can think about this in polar coordinates (r, theta) and convert to Cartesian (x, y):

```
x = (segment_length / 2) * cos(theta)
y = (segment_length / 2) * sin(theta)
```

Add `M_PI` to `theta` to get the other endpoint.